# Unity ios build work with debug mode but crash with release mode (archive ipa)

Tags: sqlite, unity-game-engine, sqlcipher

I'm trying to use sqlite with sqlcipher for unity ios game. 
I get an sqlite unity example https://github.com/takezoux2/unity-orm 
I added a method for unity to call function set key:
[DllImport("__Internal", EntryPoint = "sqlite3_key")]
private static extern int sqlite3_key(IntPtr stmHandle, string key, int len);

I compiled sqlcipher to static library (libsqlcipher.a). Add it to Assets/Plugins/iOS with header sqlite3.h, sqlite3ext.h

In Unity editor, it works without encryption. It's ok. I just want encryption work on ios devices.
I keep moving on export Xcode project, config OPENSSL_SRC in Source trees, add C flag -DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC, add search header "sqlcipher", add Security framework then run on device.

It works! There is no issue. I get the database encrypted in Document folder (i tested it with hexdump -C, SQLiteManager)

The problem only occurred after I archive the app to ipa file (using enterprise provisioning profile). I Use iFunbox to install app to device. The app crash immediately on launch.

This is what i get from crash log:
Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000

I try to replace sqlite3_key with PRAGMA key='123456';
No more crash, everything works but the output database is not encrypted.

I don't know what different between Archive and Build mode. My example works if i build directly to device (with both sqlite3_key and PRAGMA key='123456';), but archive mode does not.

I also try to import sqlcipher xcode project to unity xcode project (remove libsqlcipher.a from Plugins/iOS), set all architectures to armv7 (also try with/without -mno-thumb), add C flag -DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC, add search header "sqlcipher", add Security framework then run directly on device. It work!!!

Then i try to archive app, install app with iFunbox. Again, i get crash on launch.

I'm not sure if i'm setting something wrong with my project (https://github.com/tamhv/unity-orm-with-encrypt). Please someone take a look on this and give me advice. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you why you are crashing, but you can switch your app to Release mode and then debug it to find out.

In XCode, On the top toolbar next to the play/stop button press on the Project name to bring up the context menu and select Edit Schema.

Under Run/Debug change the Build configuration to Release.

Now run the app from XCode and hopefully you'll see the same crash but have a stack trace.

Comment: thanks @peterept I did try all stuff you suggest. I still get crash with release mode. I set all mode to Release and Run. All works but fail with Archive

Comment: really?? the release build is identical to the archive build. It should crash. That means something else is different with your adhoc install vs from xcode. One idea I would use iExplorer to copy both from your device and compare the files.

Comment: I did try to archive app with adhoc, enterprise,... All crash. But i found a solution to get over this https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/unity-ios-build-work-with-debug-mode-but-crash-with-release-mode-archive-ipa/278

Comment: Glad you figured it out someway to make it work. That EntryPoint is definately not used on iOS. (Btw: be careful with that string parameter if you ever need to set it because Unity passes strings through as UTF8 encoded strings).